# FlatList showing 10 items until render() is called

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList component that renders 20 items. When I load up the page in React Native, my FlatList shows 10 items. Once a render has occurred, the next 10 are loaded.

```
<FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, i) => String(i)}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.boardList}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <Item {...item}/>
        )}
      />
```

`data` is simply an Array of JSON objects.

Comment: What do you mean by a render has occurred? Any render if not the first one?

Comment: So if I have 20 items passed down as a prop, my FlatList will initially load 10, then load another 10. I want to know why there's this delay? I would like all 20 rendered at once.

Comment: maybe you can try this prop https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender

Comment: Not really helpful. I've already tried to source a fix from the docs.

Comment: Did you tried to move the render item to a function, and debug it to see how many times its called?

Answer (score 3):

You should set following properties

```
initialNumToRender={20}
maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
```

As the default is 10

Comment: I wanted to prevent to render one big group at time, so when I set maxToRenderPerBatch to 0 solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use `ScrollView` and `.map(() = > {})` ?

Comment: What if there are 500+ records, isn't FlatList more performant?

Answer (score 0):

Add style={{ flex: 1 }} in FlatList